# A right way to use Scanner and Random in Switch-statement with Try/catch

Tags: java, switch-statement, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a text-based game in Java. and I am going to have a lot of switch-statement with scanner, but I'm not sure which way would be the best.

What would be a best way to make switch-statement with Scanner? 
is try+catch better? or do loop?

and if I have, let's say, 10 switch-statement. Is it better to have 10 different Scanner declared for each switch-statements?

I like to have try+catch styled switch-statement with individual Scanner in it, but someone said that it is not necessary, and take too much wasting memory this way. I prefer to recall the method when a wrong type input was put in, and I think try+catch was better in this way because when it was recalled it also recalled Scanner and Random, giving us a chance to reset the input a User put in and also the randomly generated number by Random.

These code down here are examples.
and is the code here not a good code?
(just when it comes to the try+catch, scanner usages)

```
public static void levelUpAsk_111(Character chosenMember) {
    try {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dicePercent = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

        int num = sc.nextInt();
        if (num == dicePercent ) {
            System.out.println("** Congratulation!!");
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("**Which one would you like to increase?");
            System.out.println("1. +20 HP");
            System.out.println("2. +10 MP");
            System.out.println("3. +5 ATT");

            levelUpAsk_222(chosenMember);    //the second method
        } else if (num > 7 || num < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please from 1 to 6");
            levelUpAsk_111(chosenMember);   //recall itself
        } else {
            System.out.println("** Sorry..");
            sc.nextLine();

        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please integer only");
        levelUpAsk_111(chosenMember);  //recall itself
    }
}





 public static void levelUpAsk_222(Character chosenMember) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int select = sc.nextInt();

        switch (select) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("** HP has increased by 20.");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("** MP has increased by 10.");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("** ATT has incrased by 5.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("From 1 to 3");
            levelUpAsk_222(chosenMember);  //recall itself
            break;

        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Only integer please");  //recall itself
        levelUpAsk_222(chosenMember);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably have one Scanner in total.

Answer (score 1):

For switch statements, you do not need to create a new `Scanner` object each time you want to use it. You can declare it once at the beginning of each method. It is more confusing if you have to deal with multiple `Scanner` objects in your code than if you only have one.

You can create use a switch looping menu with a `default:` to catch the unlisted inputs. For example

```
switch (option){  //assuming you declared option to an int and user has inputted a value for it
    case 1:
        {
        //put some code here
        break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
        //put more code here
        break;
        }
    case 0:
        {
        //used to exit the loop
        break;
        }
    default:
        {
        System.out.println("Please enter a integer only");
        levelUpAsk_111(chosenMember); //you can do it this way, or use a do-while looped switch menu that keeps asking until a valid int is input
        }

}
```